# Use Python RegEx to find repeated target inside fixed start and end pattern

Tags: python, regex

How could I use python re to find `target1` and `target2` in a string like:

```
"aa.....target1...target2.....bb...target3...bb"
```

Which exists as:

```
"aa.*(target).*bb"
```

But does not like:

```
"aa.* bb.*(target).*bb"
```

I need to grab the part of the string that starts with `aa` and ends with `bb`.
Here's an idea `(?<=aa((?!bb).)*?)(target\d)(?=.*bb)`.

However, the pattern can't include unfixed width search.

Comment: Could you clarify what the end result should be? From your sample string it's not clear what type of characters could be between `aa` and `bb` and is target always surrounded with `**`?

Comment: target1 and target2 should be find, but not the target3. '**' is used to make the bold character, somehow it does not work. I have corrected it.

Comment: You mean like this? [`aa(?:(?!bb).)*?target.*?bb`](https://regex101.com/r/fM9rNt/1)

Comment: Or maybe I could just use two lines:first`re.search(r'aa(?P<pattern>((?!bb).)*)bb',line).group('pattern')`, then `re.findall(r'target\d',pattern)`

Comment: @sabu1234 Try http://rextester.com/URTMCW91816, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @sabu1234 Then please consider accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49598371/3832970)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do that in two steps: 1) extract substrings between the `aa` and `bb` that have no `aa` and `bb` in between with [`aa((?:(?!aa).)*?)bb`](https://regex101.com/r/qKo0sF/1) and then 2) extract all `targetXXX` substrings:

```
import re
s="aa.....target1...target2.....bb...target3...bb"
m=re.search(r'aa((?:(?!aa).)*?)bb', s)
if m:
    print(re.findall(r"target\d+", m.group(1)))

# => ['target1', 'target2']
```

See the [Python demo online](http://rextester.com/URTMCW91816).

**Pattern details**

- `aa` - a `aa` substring
- `((?:(?!aa).)*?)` - any char, that is not the starting point for a `aa` char sequence, 0 or more repetitions, as few as possible
- `bb` - a `bb` substring

The [`target\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/qKo0sF/2) pattern just matches `target` substring and any 1+ digits after it.

Answer (score 0):

To get `target1` and `target2` you could use a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead to get the part between aa and bb.

To grab the part that starts with aa and ends with bb:

[`(?<=aa).*?(?=bb)`](https://regex101.com/r/6vroWm/1)

Then you might split on a dot and remove the empty matches:

```
regex = r"(?<=aa).*?(?=bb)"
test_str = "\"aa.....target1...target2.....bb...target3...bb\""
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print filter(None, matches[0].split("."))
```

[Test](http://rextester.com/FQBS83917)

If target followed by a digit occurs twice in the string you might use 2 capturing groups:

[`(?<=aa)\.+(target\d)\.+(target\d)\.+(?=bb)`](https://regex101.com/r/ehg51A/1)